# php passing several keys to a function

Tags: php, function, session

Im using a function to update $_SESSION data

```
function session_values($key, $value)
{
   if(empty($_SESSION[$key])
   {
      $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
   }else if($_SESSION[$key] != $value)
   {
      $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
   };
};

session_values($key, $value);
```

question is, how to use this function, add a $_SESSION value equal to

```
$_SESSION['thispage']['signup']['name'] = 'Bob';
```

for example.

Comment: i have it as incvars, just wondering if its possible to use it as it is, without rewriting it to random number of keys..

Comment: If you can do the assignment in that nice one-liner that you wrote, then why are you using this function to update the values?

Comment: i wanted to have the session values filter rules in one place, right now they are spread all over, taking time to find them

Comment: I think `empty($_SESSION['key'])` should be `empty($_SESSION[$key])`

Comment: yes, missed a ), correcting it..

Comment: I meant the variable `$key` and not the string `'key'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$key = 'thispage';
$value = ['signup' => ['name' => 'Bob']];

session_values($key, $value);
```

This should have the same effect as

```
$_SESSION['thispage']['signup']['name'] = 'Bob';
```

Comment: yes, that was i was looking for, not to be lame, but i would never figure that out with double array keys, let me test

Comment: the idea was to "activate" the rewritting of the value only if the value doesnt exists already, i have a status flag also, to add it to database only if the value has changed

Comment: Ah, I see! That makes sense. In that case, my only (unsolicited) advice would be that `!isset($_SESSION[$key])` is redundant in the if condition - `empty` has an `isset` check built in.

Comment: I think I'll just remove that part of the answer then, as it was just a side note anyway.

Comment: been using isset && empty, just to make sure it has a value, so my reversal was !isset || empty, ty for the remark